# jQGrid implementation in JQuery

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have one jsp where I am using jqGrid. List is getting populated with all the values perfectly fine. But in column header I am trying to use drop down.

i.e.

```
{name:'Age',index:'age',width:120,hidden:false,search:true,edittype:'select',editoptions:{dataUrl:'/getAge'}},
```

I have one controller where I have one method like below.

```
@RequestMapping({"/getAge"})
public @ResponseBody String getAge(){
// some blah blah
}
```

Please note that, This jqGrid is in one jsp which is rendered when some specific URL is hit and for that I have separate controller in different class.  Due to this separate controller, the data in jqGrid get populated.

Question- Why my method getAge() is not getting called when page renders. 
But if I edit my URL and hit `http://localhost:3080/getAge` then this method, getAge(), is called and I see ONLY this dropdown on page with correct values.

Any thought?

Comment: Can you post us code about your jQgrid?

Comment: I wish, I could. But what else you want to know? 'Age' is the only column where I want a DropDown with some values. Its code is here(jsp + java). There are attributes in jqGrid({ }) like colName, colModel, url, datatype, mtype, rowlist and lots of others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another way to get the populated drop down in headers of jqGrid using below approach.

JSP Code :-

```
{name:'Age',index:'age',width:120,hidden:false,search:true,stype:'select',searchoptions:{value:'${age}'}},
```

And in java code I modified my method which was responsible to get jsp in which I had my jqGrid code.

Java Code-

```
    @RequestMapping({"/appPage.html"})
    public ModelAndView showAppPage(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) {
        String age = getStatuses(request); // This method call DB, get the data and add it into one stringbuffer and return.            
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("browse");
        model.addObject("age", age);        
        return model;
    }
```